# How can I convert all components of a vector into absolute value using a subprogram?

Tags: c, absolute

Just started learning C, and it would be great if you could help me with the following:

I just wrote a program that saves a 4-component vector entered by the user (using function called `save_vector`), prints it (using function called `print_vector`) and if any component is negative, it also prints it with all components in absolute value (positives) using the function `absolute_values`.

However, I am not sure how to make the function `absolute_values` work. The other two functions work just fine.

Looking forward to reading any suggestions to improve this piece of code! Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_vector(int N,float * V);
void save_vector(int N,float * V);
void absolute_values(int N, float * V);



int main(void)
{

    const int n=5;
    int i;
    float v[n];

    puts("Enter the 5 components of the vector:");
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe absolute vector is:");
    absolute_values(n, v);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        scanf("%f",V+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
}

void absolute_values(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      if (*(v+i)<0)
        v[i]=v[i]*(-1);
         printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));

}
```

Comment: `absolute_values` works. You just need to print out the results. Try calling `print_vector` again after it.

Comment: Hi @L.ScottJohnson Thanks for your answer. I just edited my question including the print() function. However, I still get the same error: `'v' undeclared (first use in this function)`. This error is tied to `if (*(v+i)<0)`in the `absolute_values` function. Looking forward to your comments. Thank you!

Comment: you are supposed to use `V` instead of `v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `V` instead of `v`. And, you miss the brace `{}` in for loop:

```
void absolute_values(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
      if (*(V+i)<0)
        V[i]=V[i]*(-1);
      printf(" %.2f ",*(V+i));
    }

}
```

You should use `V[i]` instead of `*(V+i)`. Both are fine, but `V[i]` is easier to read the code. Do not mix them together, it makes your code difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution of @Hitokiri, I am also leaving here the function `absolute_values` but this time using the conditional operator. Also, following @Hitokiri's suggestion I am using `V[i]` as it looks cleaner.

```
void absolute_values(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf(" %.2f ", ((V[i]<0)?-V[i]:V[i]));
    }
}
```